# I can't apply method "Evaluate" for my C# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a script for my learning project, it's a 3D fireballs mobile game copy.

My task to implement a mechanic of ball bouncing back from an obstacle. There are simpler ways, but, unfortunately I have to use the one attached. When I try to use method `Evaluate` I'm having this kind of log

1 In JB Rider it is:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'Evaluate'

2. In Unity it is:

> Assets\Scripts\Physics\DirectionalBounce.cs(56,48): error CS1061:
> 'Animation' does not contain a definition for 'Evaluate' and no
> accessible extension method 'Evaluate' accepting a first argument of
> type 'Animation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
> an assembly reference?)

```
using System.Collections;
using Coroutines;
using Structures;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Physics
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class DirectionalBouncePreferences
    {
        public float Duration;
        public float Height;
        public Animation Trajectory;

        public DirectionalBouncePreferences(float duration, float height, Animation trajectory)
        {
            Duration = duration;
            Height = height;
            Trajectory = trajectory;
        }
    }

    public class DirectionalBounce
    {
        private readonly Transform _bouncer;
        private CoroutineExecutor _coroutineExecutor;
        private readonly DirectionalBouncePreferences _preferences;

        public DirectionalBounce(Transform bouncer, CoroutineExecutor coroutineExecutor, DirectionalBouncePreferences preferences)
        {
            _bouncer = bouncer;
            _coroutineExecutor = coroutineExecutor;
            _preferences = preferences;
        }

        public void BounceTo(Vector3 target, Vector3 startPosition) =>
            _coroutineExecutor.Start(InerpolatePositionTo(target, startPosition));

        private IEnumerator InerpolatePositionTo(Vector3 target, Vector3 startPosition)
        {
            var timer = new UnityTimer();
            timer.Start(_preferences.Duration);

            while (timer.IsTimeUp == false)
            {
                float t = timer.ElapsedTimePercent;
                Vector3 newPosition = CalculatePosition(target, startPosition, t);
                _bouncer.transform.position = newPosition;
                yield return null;
            }
        }

        private Vector3 CalculatePosition(Vector3 target, Vector3 startPosition, float t)
        {
            return Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, target, t) +
                   Vector3.up * _preferences.Trajectory.Evaluate(t) *
    _preferences.Height;
        }
    }
}
[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be that you're calling a method named `Evaluate` on an instance of an [`Animation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.html) class - which does not have a method called `Evaluate`.

Just a guess, but perhaps you were looking for [`AnimationCurve.Evaluate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.Evaluate.html)?

Comment: Hello, mr. Matt Johnson-Pint!

Yes, thank you a lot for advice! It really worked.

I've changed my 'public Animation Trajectory' to 'public AnimationCurve Trajectory' and all is fine )

Comment: @Don'thave Great that you got your question answered! Don't forget to accept an answer if it solves your problem by clicking the checkmark on the left of the question. It signals that your question has been solved, and it gives some fun internet points too.